# latex sidewaystable, pgfplotstable produces unwanted c's in first cell

Tags: pgfplotstable, csv, sidewaystable

I'm getting a bunch of c's in the first cell of my table. The cell is blank in the .csv file. I'm not sure why and I can't figure out how to remove the c's. They are not in the .csv file. I think it might have to do with the "sidewaystable" bit. Any ideas of how to get rid of the c's? If need be, I can make a reproducible example.

[image: An example picture of the c's in the first cell of the table.]

Here's my code:

```
   \begin{sidewaystable}[ht!]
    \centering
    \caption[My short caption]{My long caption}
    \label{table:results}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        col sep=comma,
        string type,
        columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}},
        begin table={\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l c c c X X X X}},
            end table={\end{tabularx}},
        every first row/.style={before row={\toprule\addlinespace}},
        every row no 9/.style={before row={\toprule\addlinespace}},
        every row no 21/.style={before row={\toprule\addlinespace}},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
    ]{my table.csv}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

---

**Update:** Here's a reproducible example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.csv}
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
    Software,A
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{sidewaystable}[ht!]
        \centering
        \caption[My short caption]{My long caption}
        \label{table:results}
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        col sep=comma,
        string type,
        columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}},
        begin table={\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}},
            end table={\end{tabularx}},
        every first row/.style={before row={\toprule\addlinespace}},
        every row no 9/.style={before row={\toprule\addlinespace}},
        every row no 21/.style={before row={\toprule\addlinespace}},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
        ]{mytable.csv}
    \end{sidewaystable}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already added the column specifications here

```
        begin table={\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}},
```

so you need to stop `pgfplotstable` generating a new (`{cc}` by default) column spec, so add

```
 skip coltypes=true,
```

Alternatively remove the `{lX}` from the `begin table` key and set it via calls to the  `column type` key.